# Execute function without clicking in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like that in my code after executing the function **appendHtml** immediately executing clicked on the added div to perform the function **myFunction**. This is my code:

```
function myFunction()
{
    $('#Page').on('click', '*', function(e)
    {
     //console.log('execute');
    }
}

function appendHtml()
{
   $('.btn').click(function(){
   $('#Page').append('<div>Test</div>');
});
}
```

Html :

```
 <button class="btn"> click </button>
    <div id="Page"></div>
```

Comment: Call `myFunction()` after the `.append` in `appendHtml`

Comment: It looks like you shouldn't call `myFunction` more than once in the lifetime of the document, because that would attach a new click listener to `#Page` every time, and the listener would be triggered multiple times per click.

Comment: calling myFunciton seems like the wrong thing to do....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need those functions wrapping the event listeners and they really don't make sense that way either

Not 100% sure why you want `*` as selector for your click event listener but you can do something like the following to trigger it

```js
$('#Page').on('click', '*', function(e) {
  console.log('execute');
});

$('.btn').click(function() {
  var $el = $('<div>Test</div>')
  $('#Page').append($el);
  $el.click()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn"> click </button>
    <div id="Page"></div>
```

Comment: ha!  beat me by a couple seconds. :)

Comment: Be careful using `*` because if you put nested html inside #page will see "execute" numerous times per click when you click on a nested element